# Viewing queried data from mysql database in a table

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to update the code for my web page's search function, right now it is not returning anything.  I have been working with it for a little while and not getting anything out of it.

This is the HTML search code:

```
<form method="post" action="words_results1.php">
<table align="center">
  <tr>
<td>Keyword</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Keyword" /></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Author" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign=bottom>Words Posted<BR />on or before</td>
    <td valign=top>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td width="33%">Day</td>
          <td width="33%">Month</td>
          <td width="34%">Year</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
            <select name=Day>
            <?php
              echo '<option></option>';
              for($count = 1; $count <= 31; ++$count)
              {
                echo "<option>$count</option>";
              }
            ?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name=Month>
            <?php
              echo '<option></option>';
              for($count = 1; $count <= 12; $count++)
              {
                 echo "<option value=$count>".date("M", mktime(0,0,0,$count,1, 2000))."</option>";
              }
            ?>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select name=Year>
             <?php
              echo '<option></option>';
              for($count = date("Y"); $count >= 1997; $count--)
              {
                echo "<option>$count</option>";
              }
            ?>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 align=center>
      &nbsp;<BR />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>    
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['cancel']))
  {
    echo("index.html");
    exit;
  }

  $qry_string = "SELECT * FROM Words";
  $search = "";

  if(!empty($Keyword))
  {
    $End_String = "(Word LIKE '%$Keyword%' OR Title LIKE '%$Keyword%')";
    $search .="&Keyword=$Keyword";
  }

  if(!empty($Author))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
    {
      $End_String .= " AND (Author LIKE '%$Author%')";
    }
    else
    {
      $End_String = "(Author LIKE '%$Author%')";
    }
    $search .="&Author=$Author";
  }

  if(!empty($Day))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
    {
      $End_String .= " AND (DAYOFMONTH(Date_Created) = '$Day')";
    }
    else
    {
      $End_String = "(DAYOFMONTH(Date_Created) = '$Day')";
    }
    $search .="&Day=$Day";
   }

  if(!empty($Month))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
    {
      $End_String .= "AND (MONTH(Date_Created) = '$Month')";
    }
    else
    {
      $End_String = "(MONTH(Date_Created) = '$Month')";
    }
    $search .="&Month=$Month";
  }

  if(!empty($Year))
  {
    if(isset($End_String))
    {
      $End_String .= " AND (YEAR(Date_Created) = '$Year')";
    }
    else
    {
      $End_String = "(YEAR(Date_Created) = '$Year')";
    }
    $search .="&Year=$Year";
  }

  if (!isset($offset)) $offset=0;

  if(isset($End_String))
  {
    $qry_string = $qry_string." WHERE ".$End_String . " ORDER BY Date_Created DESC LIMIT $offset,101";
  }
  else
  {
    $qry_string = $qry_string." ORDER BY Date_Created DESC LIMIT $offset,101";
  }

//  echo $qry_string . "<P><HR><P>";
  $result = mysql_query($qry_string);
echo mysql_error();
?>
```

This last bit is the code that forms the table, I have an assumption that the problem lies here but honestly am not sure at this point

```
<table style="margin: 5px 15px; 5px 20px;" align="center" bgcolor="#666666" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody><tr style="background: #04C1DE; font-family: Verdana; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">
      <td style="width: 50%; padding: 5px;">
        Word
    </td>
      <td style="width: 20%; padding: 5px;">
        Author
      </td>
      <td style="width: 10%; padding: 5px;">
        Date
      </td>
      <td>Category</td>
        <td>Active?</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

    </tr>

  <?php
  $count = 1;
    $bgc = 0;


  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
    if ($count > 100) break;
    echo '<tr style="background: ';
        if ($bgc==0) echo "#FFFFFF";
        else echo "#CFEBFD";
        $bgc == 0?$bgc=1:$bgc=0;
    echo ';">';
    echo "<td><a href=../../words/display_word.php?ID=$row[ID]>$row[Title]</a></td>";
    echo "<td>$row[Author]</td><td>$row[Display_Date]</td><td>$row[category]</td>";
    if($row[active])
    {
      echo "<td>YES</td>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "<td>NO</td>";
    }
    echo "<td>$row[link_count]</td>";
    if($row[Title] != "")
    {
      echo "<td><a href=words_edit.html?ID=$row[ID]>Edit</a></td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    $count++;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: You have a bunch of `if(!empty())` where you check vars, but I don't see where any of those vars are defined. Where are you defining `$Keyword`/`$Author`/`$Day`/`$Month`? Just because you posted a form php does not automatically save the `$_POST['Keyword']` value to `$Keyword`

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: echo "<option>$count</option>"; Many places you use variable inside echo string without "" symbols. here $count will be considered as string only. Same mistake throughout your code. Even the same in sql query strings.

Comment: okay so i need to define those with statements like this then: $Keyword = $_POST['Keyword']; ?

Comment: There is no error i am getting it just is not displaying the information from the database?  I have been messing around with creating a new search function as this code has a lot of errors in it (not the original creator) would that probably be the best course of action rather than trying to get this to work>

Comment: echo "<option>$count</option>";  should be replaced by echo "<option>".$count."</option>"; 

Make the same changes throughout your program. It doesn't mean that all your problems will be solved by this. Go step by step.

Comment: @SubinThomas php vars inside double quotes are parsed - from the docs:[The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double so `echo "<option>$count</option>";` is the same as  `echo "<option>".$count."</option>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems,you are not collecting the value of

```
$Keyword=$_POST['Keyword'];
```

and add ,closing table tag to display the results in the table format correctly.

Comment: Okay, I added the $Keyword = $_POST['Keyword']; and inputted some new code      echo '<br/> Word: '.$row['Title'];
             echo '<br/> Author: '.$row['Author'];  and it is now displaying the correct search but not in the table as per the echo command, do you know how to make it insert it into the table versus the body where it is displaying now?

Comment: add </table>,closing table tag to display the results in the table format correctly.